# Importing @nuxtjs/composition-api functions in a Nuxt 3 project results in 'No matching export' error

Tags: vue-composition-api, nuxt3

I am working on a Nuxt 3 project and trying to use @nuxtjs/composition-api package to write my Vue 3 components in composition API style. However, when I import functions like useAsync and useContext from @nuxtjs/composition-api in the following manner:
`import { useAsync, useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';`

receive an error message that reads:
``No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "set"

```
node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs:1:175:
  1 │ ... as getCurrentInstance$1, ref, customRef, shallowRef, onServerPrefetch, isRef, reactive, toRefs, watch, computed, isReactive, toRaw, onBeforeMount, set } from 'vue';
```

``
I am not sure how to fix this issue. Can someone please help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you version of nuxt, what's you version, check this, and if it's not the problem exclude the node_modules and install again the dependencies